# How to draw (visualise) git workflows

Tags: git, workflow

You sure know those nice git timeline charts, visualising a git branching strategy and workflow.

I created a git workflow based upon the specific needs of a customer. To hand over my work, I´d prefer not to scan my drawings, nor to fiddle with photoshop. Are there any free tools to create those? (i.e. sure they are - but are any of these especcially well suited for the task?) Ideally theye are web-based, or at least easy to learn for such a one-time-occasion. (No, LaTeX isn´t :) )

Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags/wiki

Comment: C'mon, LaTeX is not *that* bad :)

Comment: @Jubobs - if you don't know LaTeX it is.  I like how the gitdags page says it allows you to "effortlessly" create the diagrams, and then includes 50 lines of hieroglyphics in an example.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch It's all relative. LaTeX has a lot of boilerplate and isn't the friendliest language. If I had to produce Git graphs for the Web, as opposed to an academic paper or presentation, I most likely wouldn't use gitdags.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can describe your flow using JS code. Here is [GitGraph.js](https://www.nicoespeon.com/gitgraph.js)

> - a simple JavaScript library which is meant to help you visually presenting git branching stuff like a git workflow, a tricky git command or whatever git tree you'd have in mind.

[image: GitGraph.js - template "metro"]

Comment: This is perfect and does exactly what I needed. Very easy to setup and use.

Comment: dopest answer is this!

Comment: While GitGraph.js does give a pretty easy to use mechanism to generate these graph, I have found their documentation to be pretty lacking. If you want to do anything outside what's described in the tutorials, prepare to go digging deep.

Comment: @austinbruch Totally agreed. I just picked it up after seeing this verified answer, and got descended into a documentation hell, since what I want to do is off the tutorial, and their documentation, just like you said, is insufficient.

Answer (score 23):

There are:

- [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) - free (Java)
- [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com) - web-based
- [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) - web-based, free, [open source](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio)
- OmniGraffle - mac only, paid with free trial, my personal favourite
- MS Visio

...to name just a few. There's a lot of GUI tools for this.

If you'd like to write some code and generate pictures out of it, take a look at GraphViz or Ditaa.

Comment: I liked Draw.io. The only thing I did not like about it, is it saves as an XML file that must be open on the draw.io site. And, it does not print in Landscape for real. :( But it sure did a fine job of allowing me to crate a GitFlow for my company.

Comment: draw.io allows exporting to .vsdx

Comment: Draw.io (now diagrams.net) worked well for me. If anyone wants a template, you can use mine as a starting place: https://gist.github.com/bryanbraun/8c93e154a93a08794291df1fcdce6918

Answer (score 4):

I like [Visualizing Git](https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/), which is [open source](https://github.com/git-school/visualizing-git) and runs in your browser. You type in git commands, and it creates the graph.

The below graph was generated by this sequence:

```
git commit -m "second commit"
git commit
git commit
git checkout HEAD^^
git checkout -b feature
git commit
git commit
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

[image: graph generated by Visualizing Git]

Answer (score 2):

Now that [GitHub pages do support mermaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689446/6309) (Feb. 2022), you can integrate mermaid graph representing a Git workflow:

```
gitGraph :                     
options                        
{"key": "value",               
"nodeWidth": 150               
}                              
end                            
    commit                     
    branch newbranch           
    checkout newbranch         
    commit                     
    commit                     
    checkout master            
    commit                     
    commit                     
    merge newbranch
```

Result:

[image: GitGraph]

Warning: was in [Beta in 2021](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2011), but now (Feb. 2022) [referenced by the official documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/README?id=git-graph-exclamation-experimental), still as "experimental".