# How to install Mermaid to render flowcharts in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, readme, mermaid

I'm trying to render a flowchart in a markdown file using Mermaid to place into a ReadMe.md file in my GitHub repository.

In this link ([https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.0.0-rc.8/README.md](http://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.0.0-rc.8/README.md)), there's an example code snippet for the Mermaid installation:

````
    ```
    https://unpkg.com/mermaid@7.1.0/dist/
    ```
````

I included that code, then tried to make the flowchart in the next code snippet:

````
    ```
    graph TD;
        A-->B;
        A-->C;
        B-->D;
        C-->D;
    ```
````

But all it does is print that text out in the markdown file when I preview it.

How can I achieve my stated results or is not possible?

Comment: Just FYI, Webstorm Markdown Settings has a one-click "Install" option for Mermaid and also for PlantUML support (Settings => Markdown). After installing it, the Markdown editor shows the rendered diagram in the preview tab (IDEA Markdown editor has a split view of left: Markdown source, right: rendered view). The bundled Markdown plugin must be enabled of course (by default it is, I think).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, github-flavoured markdown doesn't support rendering of mermaid graphs. See [this issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/533) for more information and finding comfort in other peoples quest of this feature ;)

If your are using VS Code, you can use [this extension](https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-markdown-mermaid) to preview your mermaid code blocks inside markdown but note that this does not render once you put it on github. To include the chart on github you will have to render it to a file, though someone suggested somehow using the [online mermaid editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ3JhcGggVERcbkFbQ2hyaXN0bWFzXSAtLT58R2V0IG1vbmV5fCBCKEdvIHNob3BwaW5nKVxuQiAtLT4gQ3tMZXQgbWUgdGhpbmt9XG5DIC0tPnxPbmV8IERbTGFwdG9wXVxuQyAtLT58VHdvfCBFW2lQaG9uZV1cbkMgLS0-fFRocmVlfCBGW2ZhOmZhLWNhciBDYXJdXG4iLCJtZXJtYWlkIjp7InRoZW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdCJ9fQ) to render it and retrieve an URL to a rendered version.

Actually, let me try to insert the example chart from the link on the previousely mentioned page... and, no. We get a `Failed to upload image; the format is not supported`-error.

So you will need to save it as an image first.

Answer (score 16):

I created a Firefox & Chrome extension that wasn't available at the time of the first answer: [Github + Mermaid](https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension)

To use it you will need to specify `mermaid` as a language:

````
```mermaid
graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;
```
````

This works on:

- PR and issues
- Comments
- Gists

(both on preview and save)

PS: I'm not sure whether it's right or not to advertise my own work here, but I feel it answers the questions.

Comment: thanks for providing this! due to github's narrow display column, I also had to add this extension to solve the issue where some large diagrams were squeezed.
https://github.com/mdo/github-wide

Answer (score 9):

Feb. 2022, Markdown pages now officially support Mermaid:
(Note: Aug. 2022, [GitHub wiki pages too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300843/6309))

See:

> ### [Include diagrams in your Markdown files with Mermaid](https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/)
>
> [Mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid#readme) is a JavaScript based diagramming and charting tool that takes Markdown-inspired text definitions and creates diagrams dynamically in the browser. Maintained by **[Knut Sveidqvist](https://github.com/knsv)**, it supports a bunch of different common diagram types for software projects, including flowcharts, UML, Git graphs, user journey diagrams, and even the dreaded Gantt chart.
>
> Working with Knut and also the wider community at **[CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/)**, we’ve rolled out a change that will allow you to create graphs inline using [Mermaid syntax](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/n00b-syntaxReference?id=syntax-structure):
>
> [image: Example]

[Gist supports mermaid too](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-28-gists-now-support-mermaid-diagrams/).

---

Jan 2022, while GitHub Markdown does not yet support Mermaid, this is on the roadmap:

"[Mermaid diagrams can be displayed within Markdown #372](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/372)"

> Just as language-specific code blocks can be added to Markdown, you'll be able to add a Mermaid diagram using a code block that specifies mermaid as its language identifier. For example:
>
> ```
> graph TD;
>    A-->B;
>    A-->C;
>    B-->D;
>    C-->D;
> ```
>
> The Markdown code block above uses Mermaid syntax to display this flowchart in the rendered Markdown:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1767415/147986289-f8283c0b-aa5e-4381-bd69-876edeef12d9.png]

And:

> Another example from the Mermaid website shows how straightforward text can be used to create rich diagrams:
>
> ```
> sequenceDiagram
>    autonumber
>    Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
>    loop Healthcheck
>        John->>John: Fight against hypochondria
>    end
>    Note right of John: Rational thoughts!
>    John-->>Alice: Great!
>    John->>Bob: How about you?
>    Bob-->>John: Jolly good!
> ```
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1767415/148230142-63d64ec6-8157-4578-a4a8-a63e386b5cb9.png]

Comment: Though the ticket is marked as "Open", "Today, we're excited to add native support for Mermaid wherever Markdown is supported (e.g., issues, repositories, discussions, gists)." had me excited to be able to use this new feature, well, today. Should have been "we're excited to announce we've added this feature to our roadmap."

Comment: @ksclarke True. It is not quite there yet ;)

Comment: Arrived https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/

Comment: @Kariem Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use mermaid-cli https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli for generating diagrams. you can produce .svg, .png or .pdf file whatever you want.

Run following command after installing mermaid-cli

```
mmdc -i input.mmd -o output.png
```

here input.mmd is your mermaid file which contains

```
 graph TD;
        A-->B;
        A-->C;
        B-->D;
        C-->D;
```

in your case.

Comment: Now moved to https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli

Answer (score 6):

Another solution in moving your repository to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com).
It natively supports mermaid in all markdown files.

[Gitlab Markdown Tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html)