# Mermaid syntax error on trying render a diagram on Github .md file

Tags: github, mermaid, editor.md

I've followed this [MermaId tutorial](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram) but when I try put into my .md file on Github an error is raised:

[image]

This works perfectely on [Live editor.](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit/#eyJjb2RlIjoiICAgIHNlcXVlbmNlRGlhZ3JhbVxuICAgICAgICBhdXRvbnVtYmVyXG4gICAgICAgIEFsaWNlLT4-Sm9objogSGVsbG8gSm9obiwgaG93IGFyZSB5b3U_XG4gICAgICAgIGxvb3AgSGVhbHRoY2hlY2tcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIEpvaG4tPj5Kb2huOiBGaWdodCBhZ2FpbnN0IGh5cG9jaG9uZHJpYVxuICAgICAgICBlbmRcbiAgICAgICAgTm90ZSByaWdodCBvZiBKb2huOiBSYXRpb25hbCB0aG91Z2h0cyFcbiAgICAgICAgSm9obi0tPj5BbGljZTogR3JlYXQhXG4gICAgICAgIEpvaG4tPj5Cb2I6IEhvdyBhYm91dCB5b3U_XG4gICAgICAgIEJvYi0tPj5Kb2huOiBKb2xseSBnb29kISIsIm1lcm1haWQiOiJ7XG4gIFwidGhlbWVcIjogXCJkZWZhdWx0XCJcbn0iLCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlLCJhdXRvU3luYyI6dHJ1ZSwidXBkYXRlRGlhZ3JhbSI6ZmFsc2V9)

Code:

````
    ```mermaid
    sequenceDiagram
        autonumber
        Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
        loop Healthcheck
            John->>John: Fight against hypochondria
        end
        Note right of John: Rational thoughts!
        John-->>Alice: Great!
        John->>Bob: How about you?
        Bob-->>John: Jolly good!
    ```
````

Someone can help me find my error on try write it on Github

Comment: Did the mermaid graph ever work? Github doesn't offer much support for rendering mermaid graphs. Are you using plain md? Did you consider exporting and using it as a SVG?

Comment: Q1 2022: [This is coming soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689446/6309)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I struggle on a similar problem.

1. With GitHub, do you mean [GitHub pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages)?
2. Could you find a solution to it?

Personally, I have a setup with Jekyll. Here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956232/mermaid-not-rendered-in-jekyll-page) on how to setup mermaid correctly for jekyll.

Interestingly, I just posted your mermaid into my jekyll page and the result is:
[image: akward mermaid diagram]
If I put it into `<div>` tags with class mermaid. Setup I used was [this](https://jojozhuang.github.io/tutorial/jekyll-diagram-with-mermaid/).

And if I use the jekyll [spaceship-plugin](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship), ist renders to:
[image: nice mermaid diagram]
I guess, that this what it should like. Am I right?

Therefore, so far, for me mermaid works based on the spaceship plugin, but not by "natively" referencing the mermaid JavaScript. I do not know if spaceship will work with GitHub pages, however, definitely within GitHub pages (which is based on Jekyll), you may also add plugins. See [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll) for further details.